# will transaction roll back if I don't use setRollBackOnly?

Tags: java, spring, web

I have seen lots of ways to use transaction:in the `doInTransaction()` method,use try catch,and use `status.setRollBackOnly` in `catch` block,like this:

```
transactionTemplate
            .execute(new TransactionCallback() {
                public Object doInTransaction(TransactionStatus transactionStatus) {
                    try {
                        doThings();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        transactionStatus.setRollbackOnly();
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            });
```

I am very curious that if I don't use `setRollBackOnly`,Will the transaction roll back when `doThings()` throw exception?

thanks a lot;

Comment: I would say, that depends on the kind of exception. By catching the exception you take responsibility to decide how to continue. If you don't call setRollbackOnly(), you don't tell the transaction manager that something evil has happened, so it will at least try to commit the transaction. That will not be possible if the exception had something to do with data integrity or was an sql exception. Generally I would not recommend to suppress this information.

Comment: @UweAllner Then,What kind of exception will make rolling back,and what not?

Comment: All subclasses of RuntimeException.